# How well do Macs work with Windows Home Server?

Tags: windows, mac, time-machine, windows-home-server

If a network has a Windows Home Server setup, how well can a Mac running Leopard 10.5.8 take advantage of the services provided by the Windows Home Server system? I'm specifically looking for Time Machine functionality, but am curious what other features could be used by the Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sending Time Machine backups to a volume on the Windows Server machine, you will want to use [iTimeMachine](http://www.xiotios.com/itimemachine.html) to make things easier. Printer sharing and File sharing is also fairly painless between Mac and Windows Server.

[This](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-access-windows-home-server-from-mac-os-x/) Redmond Pie article on connecting to shares may also interest you.

Answer (score 2):

HP's WHS line, the [MediaSmart Servers](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/mediasmart-server/), have official support for Time Machine backups and it works great in my experience. (Although, they do not support the "Restore System from Backup" feature of Time Machine.)

You can of course also access the WHS network shares from a Mac, as well as the media sharing features. The main limitation you'll run into is the lack of access to the WHS admin console from a Mac.

Comment: you can remote into your WHS machine and run the console from there if necessary. There is CoRD and an official Microsoft RDP client available free of charge.